# Is there a reliable/trusted way to get your SVN working copy completely clean before building?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I've looked and looked and I can't seem to find what I need here.  Optimally, I'd like CruiseControl.NET to do the following before moving to the build process:

- If the working folder doesn't exist, check out from SVN (this isn't a problem)
- Make the working folder completely pristine, as though it was freshly checked out of SVN:

  - No ignored files
  - No modified files (because I'll be modifying the AssemblyInfo.cs files for .NET projects before building)
  - No missing files/directories (This is highly unlikely, but just being complete here)
- I do not want to simply delete the working folder every run because some of these projects will be large.

I know from experience that deleting everything but the hidden .svn/_svn folder at the root of the working folder and then doing an SVN update will accomplish this, but this seems like a hack.

Is anyone else doing this and how?

Comment: Sounds like a case for a full export, doesn't it?

Comment: @Pekka - So, basically keep the SVN working copy in a folder of its own and then wipe the "real" working copy and export on every build?  Sounds about right.  I know you probably don't care about the rep, but answer it here and I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `svn export` from a working copy instead of from the source repo. It is the official method [recommended by the TortoiseSVN team](http://tortoisesvn.net/unversion.html).

If you need to get rid of local modifications, you are probably best off exporting directly from the repository.

Answer (score 2):

The Subvesion source control block already supports this. You need to set the cleanCopy option for your block.

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Subversion_(svn)

This will delete the working copy files and retrieve the designated revision anew each time.

Comment: Two things: 1. most important, I don't want to delete the working copy (see my final bullet above) due to the possible size issues.  2. I've actually tried this and I get weird permissions issues.  The first build it works, second it fails, third it works, second it fails, .... go to infinity.